# 4e Skills in D&D 3.5?

Tags: dnd-4e, dnd-3.5e, house-rules

One of my favorite facets of 4e is the new simplified skill system, particularly the reduced skill lists.

- `Stealth` vs `Hide` and `Move Silently`.
- `Athletics` vs `Jump` and `Climb`

Is there a set of rules to apply the reduced skill list to 3.5?  I think I remember a "4th edition preview" that did just that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to the simplified Pathfinder system, in late 3.5 some people used the Saga system skill rules, which were simplified...  From the [SWSE Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Roleplaying_Game_%28Wizards_of_the_Coast%29):

> Skill points have been eliminated. Characters have a number of "trained" skills they can pick based on their class and Intelligence bonus. When a character makes a skill check, they roll a d20 and add half their character level + any other bonuses. If they roll for a trained skill they get a +5 bonus to the die roll, and certain applications of some skills cannot be attempted unless trained in the skill. Skills themselves have been simplified and integrated, with such skills as Deception covering the former skills of Bluff, Disguise, and Forgery. The Mechanics skill now encompasses Repair, Disable Device, and Demolitions (as well as crafting devices in the expansion books). Likewise, the new Perception skill combines the Spot, Search, Sense Motive, and Listen skills.

Oh, and there's an [abbreviated 4e preview skill list on dnd4.com](http://dnd4.com/phb)... It's not "for 3.5" but it's as simple as deciding what your skill list is right?

Answer (score 6):

I don't know of any official D&D material for a reduced skill list.  However, [Pathfinder reduced the number of skills to 26](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills) from [3.5's 36](http://www.d20srd.org/indexes/skills.htm).  Pathfinder also simplified the calculations for trained/untrained and how ranks are determined.

Answer (score 0):

Other resources especially from AEG will help with this transition.  Or another popular house rule I use in 3.5e is to increase skill point knowing how many each pc needs, and I also have certain times when I award pc with free ranks in skills, growing up in royal family might help with related knowledge skill.  Same applies for the physical skills characters that make effort telling me that when mages are studying for spells hes doing massive workouts, having other pcs test his hiding skills.  I have brought many 4e rules to 3.5e and other way I find both games more fun incorporating the rules my group may need.